# How to set and retrieve multiple messages within a handler without new messages overwriting previously set ones?

Tags: session, haskell, yesod

Sometimes, a web site/app needs to display multiple messages to the user following a request. Unfortunately, Yesod's message facility (if I understand well [the docs](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/sessions#_messages)) seems to be limited to a single message per request, with each new message overwriting the previous one. I thought that I could use a writer monad inside the handler to get around this, rendering the message list to HTML before saving it with 'setMessage', but being fairly new to Haskell, I don't have a clue how to integrate an additional monad to the handler's type signature (in fact, I'm not even sure whether this is feasible or not). So, I would like to know what is the recommended approach for multiple session messages in Yesod? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You read the book correctly, you can have only one message. But you can display any HTML in that message. You can use `blaze-html` to generate a message with any HTML that you want.

This snippet does just that:

```
import Text.Blaze.Html5

-- Create a message.
message :: Html
message = do
    p "Welcome to my site"
    p "Your account was created successfully"       

-- Use the message in your handler.
getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = defaultLayout $ do
    setTitle "Yesod Web Service Homepage"    
    setMessage $ message
    $(widgetFile "home")
```

To the user of your home page it will be like you have two messages. To learn more about `blaze-html` take a look [here](http://jaspervdj.be/blaze/tutorial.html).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer @RodrigoTaboada, but I had already figured that out. What still puzzles me though (and my question was not clear on that point) is how to set multiple session messages at various places in the code for a given request (e.g. set a message in getHomeR, then set another one inside defaultLayout, etc.).